# What does a dispatcher do if an aircraft can't stay on a NAT route due to a communications failure?

Tags: airline-operations, flight-plans, oceanic, dispatch, diversion

For example, a flight is enroute form from LEJ (Leipzig/Halle Airport, Germany) to MIA (Miami, USA) on a North Atlantic Track (NAT). Now suppose there is an issue with the communication or CPDLC of the aircraft which is a mandatory requirement flight over the North Atlantic.

Now what back up plan will the dispatcher do with reference to an updated flight plan? The aircraft cannot fly the NAT level and have to drop down to a lower flight level.

Comment: Why would the plane not be able to fly the NAT level, or had to drop to lower flight level?

Comment: https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aip_html/part2_enr_section_7.8.html

Comment: Hi Jan , thanks a lot..  Since its mandatory to have CPDLC and communication with the ATC over the North Atlantic.  If the CPDLC fails there will be no communication with the ATC. Will it still be OK to fly the track with  no communication.. and what  is needed to be done by the Flight dispatcher when the  flight is enroute..

Answer (score 2):

Every flight within the NAT region is issued with an oceanic clearance that includes routing, altitude and speed. In case of communications failure the aircraft shall adhere to the last acknowledged clearance. The clearance ensures a conflict-free crossing of the Atlantic.

Besides mandatory CPDLC there is a requirement to be able contact ATC via radio operators using long-distance HF radios, and if flying well north of the track system using VHF relays in Iceland and Greenland. One can also use other aircraft in the Atlantic to relay messages should both CPDLC and HF fail. On top of that as a last resort it is possible use satellite telephone if AC is equipped with one. But basically, after entering the NAT region with an oceanic clearance it is possible to cross the pond without talking to anyone.

To answer your question: the flight dispatcher plays no role in case of communication failure. Indeed, if the plane is able to contact dispatch it is very likely it can contact a radio operator or ATC.